# how to turn of stereo when buzzer is activated

Tags: switches, gps, stereo

I have a GPS geo-fence warning system that activates a buzzer alarm when the vehicle enters a area it should not.

The problem is if you are playing the stereo loud we can not hear the buzzer so what i want to do is:

If the buzzer is activated (current is sent from GPS unit to the buzzer) I need the buzzer current to somehow stop power going to the stereo so the stereo goes silent if the buzzer is sounding.

Does anyone know how I would do this? Some sort of resistor switch?

Comment: Definitely You're playing music too loud.

Comment: And you want us to guess the make and model of all the equipment? Please edit your question and provide links to the datasheets.

Comment: Replace the buzzer with a big red light and keep the music on.

Answer (score 1):

What is the voltage the buzzer run from? Assume it run from 12volt, you can install a resetable self latching 12 volt relay in parallel to that buzzer. The normally-closed contact of this relay can serve as the switch for the stereo.

When you have the GPS event, the relay will latch and disconnect the stereo and killing the loud music so you can hear the buzzer well.

After the GPS event is clear or when the buzzer is no longer sounding, you may reset the latched relay and enjoy your music again.

Edit:

[image: The wiring diagram.]

I am assuming your stereo is running on 12V too.... In that case, simply wire up the  whole thing as shown in the schematic. The reset button is a normally closed momentary type. You have to choose your relay based on its contacts capacity and the current rating of your stereo. Use of under rated relay will risk your installation catching fire. Pretty serious. Pls be certain on this.

You must check on the relay coil resistance too. Some high power capable relay will have strong coils with low resistance. The relay coil together with the buzzer should not be a very heavy load for the GPS circuitry.

GPS event will sound the buzzer and trigger the relay too. This will immediately cut the power supply to the stereo. Once the contact of the relay is closed, current for the relay is no longer required from the buzzer circuit but it will sustain itself through the normally closed push button switch.

Pressing the switch kills the relay and returns power to the stereo.

The diode is to prevent the external 12V from flowing back into the GPS circuitry. Use any 1 Amp diode such as 1N4004.

Comment: Yes - its a 12 volt. Is there any way the latch can reset by itself? Just need the stereo to turn off when GPS event occurs and turn back on automatically when GPS event ends. Thanks for your help

Comment: The lead wires going to the buzzer is accessible to you?

Comment: yes - all wires to buzzer and stereo are accessible. Thanks

Comment: Answer is edited with new details given about the question.